# Use async data when creating factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In one of my apps, I want to use $resource to clean up the read/write operations, but the url has a prefix I can't know until I finish loading the preference document. I don't know how to cleanly delay the factory creation until that ajax has come back.

This is similar to the "Don't initialize the app until some ajax data comes back" problem but all examples I could find (using `$route.resolve`) only delay the controller, not the factory.

Here's my ideal [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevearm/R6YCS/).

I think the [GitHub pull #3295](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3295) might just magically make the fiddle above work, but I'm looking for alternatives until it gets merged.

My current fix is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stevearm/WNBwv/1/), but that results in multiple `$resource` instances, and a `resolve` clause for every route that needs the factory, or the preference document.

Comment: +1 Nominating this question to be placed as an example in [ask] section.

Comment: ok, I forked and created a fiddle that uses a small bit of refactoring, and also injects the ui.router module to achieve your desired result.  I actually have never created an Angular app with the default ngRoute module, but I dont' think it has an equivalent service method that allows route interception and promise handling prior to allowing the app to handle the route.  That small feature makes things like this possible.  I also provided a link to one of my github repos with production code that achieves a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

### Inject Angular Ui Router, and refactor your Doc as a provider factory instead of a service factory

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LongLiveCHIEF/5kSbC/

1. Change your factory to a provider (still using the `.factory` method), and your prefs service to be handled pre-route resolution with ui.router.
2. Your prefs will then configure the `prefix` of your former `docs` factory  (now refactored as a provider), before you send a router to your app or activate the initiation of an app state.
3. THEN you resolve the Doc factory data via async promise resolution, prior to controller instantiation.

This would then automatically make the data available to the `$state` (ui.router)

The `.when()` in [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) allows you to match a route pattern, then do some special configuration before you fire your route handling. I actually *just* released a small app last night that had a similar challenge to solve (I needed to seed the view with some user specific information before initializing the app or handling the route).  You can see my actual code here:

https://github.com/NormalGravity/evsvillas.com/blob/master/app/src/app.js.

Check out lines 22-38.  They wait for a promise to resolve (which seeds a singleton with configuration data) before deciding what route to send to the application.

A few useful bits of reading:

- AngularJS developer guide on [Providers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and [Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) (note the availability during different app phases). This actually isn't what you think it is. These two guides discuss how using `factory`,`service`, and `provider` in different ways and app phases turn them into Services or Providers (think `$http` vs `$httpProvider`)
- Angular Ui Router [wiki Page on the StateManger](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).  This details the concepts that allow the pre-route factory configuration

Comment: I think this will result in multiple copies of the `$resource` factory, and it requires a `resolve` clause in every route I have. With those restrictions lifted, I was going to use this: http://jsfiddle.net/stevearm/WNBwv/1/ so my controllers don't have to know about any of it. I edited to question to clarify this.

Comment: both the provider and the service are singletons, so nothing is going to result in mutliple copies of anything.  Your concern about a resolve for every route is one of the reasons I specified you switch to `ui.router` as opposed to `ngRoute`. When you resolve data this way, it resolves to a `state` and not a view/route.  This data is then accessible by any sibling states, and can be mutated as needed on your $scope and $states throughout the app.  If you use the code from my fiddle, your prefs will be resolved to the parent state of the entire application, meaning you do it once, and that's it

Comment: Your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevearm/WNBwv/1/) for your fix has a few things that will also cause you some issues. First you've entered an infinite loop in your config block. then, in your doc factory, you need to start with a return statement. Right now, there's no way to call the function inside, so nothing will be returned at all. Another thing to keep in mind, is that your factories are coded as services, and won't be available to your app's config (see the service/provider links in my answer). Also, angular factories are singletons. You can't use a constructor.

Comment: I can't find the infinite loop and it seems to run fine, could you explain it? Also, after reading more on providers and ui-router, I understand your solution a bit better. I set up a [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevearm/WNBwv/2/) which seems to wire the providers together just fine so they work off the same http call's promise. I'm not getting any of ui-router's advantage, because I can't figure out how to get a parent state working to allow me just a single resolve argument.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, delayed service providing is currently not an "Angular native" ability.

The workaround is to get the $provide provider out of a config function.

Enough talked, code now (comments explain the rest):

*HTML*

```
<!-- test will be holding the lazy registered value -->
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="TestController">
   {{test}}
</body>
```

*JS* (updated comments)

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

// prepare the external reference holder
var provide;

// use a config function to externalize the $provide provider
App.config(function($provide) {
    provide = $provide;
});

// delayed $provide use with a timeout
App.run(function($timeout) {
    // async function with one of the followings
    // - $timeout
    // - $q
    // - $http
    // which actually register the value (could be a factory or what you want)
    // at t+1000ms
    $timeout(function() {
        // here I provide a simple object but you can pass a $resource !
        provide.value('Test', {a:1});
    },1000);
});

// watch the existence of the service
// OR broadcast an event from $rootScope
// OR the way you want to tell the service now exists
App.controller('TestController', function($injector, $scope) {
    var unwatch = $scope.$watch(function() { 
        return $injector.has('Test');
    }, function(has) {
        if(has) {
            $scope.test = $injector.get('Test');
            unwatch();
        }
    });
});
```

Here the app is not lazy loaded but the value that depends on async data is.
Delaying the whole application loading for a simple data is not good for user experience.
Load the app, display the page, tell the user data are being fetched, and finally display the fetched data.

**UPDATE**

If you want a more "promise oriented" approach, please consider the following code that wraps the value registering in a promise:

*JS*

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.factory('MyLazyFactory', function($timeout) {
    // here I delay with $timeout but
    // it can be delayed with $http !
    // ($timeout returns a promise, resolved with the inner returned value)
    return $timeout(function() {
        // here I return an object but
        // it can be a $resource !
        return {a:1};
    },1000);
});

App.controller('TestController', function(MyLazyFactory, $scope) {
    MyLazyFactory.then(function(myFactory) {
        // here I really get the value returned by the timeout callback
        $scope.test = myFactory;
    });
});
```

Keep commenting if not clear.

**UPDATE**
(to solve the particular case of $resource and promise wrapping, pointed out by Brian Vanderbusch)

Using promise oriented approach you will need two levels of promise wrapping as you will see in my version of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6YCS/1/).

*JS*

```
angular.module('myApp',["ngResource"])

.service("LazyPrefs", [ "$http", function($http) {
    return $http.post("/echo/json/", "json={\"prefix\":\"/echo/json/test\"}")
        .then(function(response) { return response.data; });
}])

.factory("LazyDoc", [ "$resource", "LazyPrefs", function($resource, LazyPrefs) {
    return LazyPrefs.then(function(Prefs) {
        console.log("Using " + Prefs.prefix + " as prefix");
        return $resource(Prefs.prefix + "/:docId", { docId:"@id" });
    });
}])

.controller("MainCtrl", [ "$scope", "$http", "LazyDoc", function($scope, $http, LazyDoc) {
    LazyDoc.then(function(Doc) {
        $scope.doc = new Doc({ name: "Steve", photo: "profile.jpg" });
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I'm confused on how the proposed technique is an alternative.  From what I can see, there are no promises resolved to anything before all the apps factories and such would be registered, and in this case, that means it's too late. injection into the controller wouldn't be enough, because the data would need to cascade up, and that's not how angular is designed to function. At what point does your value get passed anywhere? The injector never invokes any functions, so it's not going to be assigned your value.  Can you make any edits to clarify?

Comment: The line with `provide.value('Test', {a:1});` is where I register the service out of the initialization process so that the app can load and the service can be lazy loaded. I will clarify but don't undrrstand the down vote.

Comment: That definitely clears things up a bit, but his problem is that he needs to initialize and resolve data before the app finishes initialization due to a chain of dependencies.  Lazy Loading wouldn't work for this use case.

Comment: With the promise oriented approach, only the services (or controllers etc.) which have a dependency on the lazy resolved service, would have to wrap calls to the latter in a `then` call. Not the whole dependency chain.

Comment: I know, but his controllers don't have the dependency... his service and provider factories do. He needs one factory to resolve, then use data from that first to seed pieces of the second, THEN initialize the rest of the app so that a controller can resolve the dependency correctly based on it's dynamic configuration from pre-run phase data resolution

Comment: I think I got both the Prefs and Doc injectables working off the same promise in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevearm/WNBwv/2), so the controllers can treat them like 'complete' objects, but I'm still relying on `resolve` clauses in $route or $state, so I'm not there yet.